# How to decompress the hadoop reduce output file end with snappy?

Tags: hadoop, snappy

Our hadoop cluster using snappy as default codec. Hadoop job reduce output file name is like `part-r-00000.snappy`. JSnappy fails to decompress the file bcz JSnappy requires the file start with SNZ. The reduce output file start with some bytes 0 somehow.

How could I decompress the file?

Comment: Similar to a question asked on the hadoop mailing lists - http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-mapreduce-user/201305.mbox/%3C1165688733-1369155084-cardhu_decombobulator_blackberry.rim.net-1208212455-@b4.c16.bise7.blackberry%3E

Comment: `hadoop fs -text snappy_file` works. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use "Hadoop fs -text" to read this file and pipe it to txt file.
ex:

hadoop fs -text part-r-00001.snappy > /tmp/mydatafile.txt