# finding out the raw parquet file size?

Tags: hadoop, parquet

is there a way to figure out what the uncompressed file size is for a parquet file compressed in snappy? I have a lot of parquet files in a HDFS directory and I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to calculate the file size if that data was uncompressed.

Answer (score 0):

You can just try to uncompress the data and see how much space it consumes. See [How to decompress the hadoop reduce output file end with snappy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805149/how-to-decompress-the-hadoop-reduce-output-file-end-with-snappy)

Maybe there's a more elegant way I'm not aware of